what is the definition of a necessary fact in the contingency argument?
how can we define a necessary fact in the contingency argument in a way which does not lead us to the ontological argument? (exists in all possible worlds)
the contingency argument is:
A contingent being (a being such that if it exists, it could have not-existed) exists.
All contingent beings have a sufficient cause of or fully adequate explanation for their existence.
The sufficient cause of or fully adequate explanation for the existence of contingent beings is something other than the contingent being itself.
The sufficient cause of or fully adequate explanation for the existence of contingent beings must either be solely other contingent beings or include a non-contingent (necessary) being.
Contingent beings alone cannot provide a sufficient cause of or fully adequate explanation for the existence of contingent beings.
Therefore, what sufficiently causes or fully adequately explains the existence of contingent beings must include a non-contingent (necessary) being.
Therefore, a necessary being (a being such that if it exists, it cannot not-exist) exists.

Please improve your post by formulating the "contingency argument", thanks.

See here for Metaphysical necessity.

@لوسيفر جبريل The last sentence from your addition gives the definition for necessary fact, just replace "being" by "fact". Then it says: "if it exists, it cannot not-exist". Hence your definition of the contingency argument presupposes the answer to your question. - A meaningful question would be instead: Are there other definitions for "necessary" than the definition from the possible-worlds ontology. - Do not entangle the definition of "necessary" with a question about the validity or non-validity of the contingency argument.

@JoWehler so the definition would be 'a fact that if exists it exists in all possible worlds'?

@لوسيفر جبريل Yes. See also Mauro's link: Standford Online Encylopedia is a good source for many philosophical definitions, questions, issues and proposals.

The sense of 'necessary' in the cosmological argument is something like self-sufficient, or requiring no explanation of its existence, or not being dependent on other things for a causal explanation. For example, my existence is contingent on that of my parents. If they did not exist, I would not. A necessary thing is one without this kind of contingency: nothing outside of it is needed to provide a cause or explanation of it. This is not the same as logical necessity. In classical logic if something is logically necessary then a contradiction follows from it failing to hold.

This article has a useful account.

Background knowledge (can be skipped): Comparing the ontological argument and the contingency argument is similar to comparing deductive reasoning to inductive reasoning. The ontological argument starts with the idea of God and then it tries to prove that God must exist. The contingency argument starts with the idea that we are contingent things and tries to prove that a non-contingent thing exist. I use the word "thing", because I don't want to insinuate/confuse that a non-contingent being must be a conscious being because that is not an axiom the argument takes.
You want to know: How do we make the contingency argument not lead to the ontological argument.
Answer 1: The contingency argument already does this, in a way. It does this by concluding that a thing exist and not that this thing is God (as most westerners know the word). So the argument does not end the same as the ontological argument because this thing isn't necessarily God, it is only possibly God.
Answer 2: If you meant how do we not end with the conclusion that a thing must exist that isn't possible to not exist, then one popular argument is the infinite regress contingency rebuttal. It's the idea that an infinite chain of contingent beings would not necessarily require a non-contingent being. If you find the argument convincing enough to be a possibility (however improbable that possibility is) then you can conclude that it's probable other scenarios exist that also don't require a non-contingent thing. Therefore you would conclude that a contingent thing does not require a non-contingent thing that "exists in all possible worlds".
So we don't actually have to go re-defining words like you asked, instead we found a rebuttal to the contingency argument that shifts it's conclusion to not necessitate a necessary being.
And just to be clear I'm not claiming the infinite regress argument is convincing or unconvincing. I'm using it to highlight one way someone might conclude the above.
